# Leak from Twitter TWRequest handler

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, twitter, automatic-ref-counting

Wrapping up my first project using ARC. Imagine my surprise then, to discover a leak almost immediately. Does anyone have any insight as to why the following code would leak with symbol identifier: 'dispatch_queue_create':

This is using an overly simplified TWRequest handler in iOS5 w/ ARC:

```
- (void)loadSomeTweets
{


NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?"];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"%23WatchingTheVoice", @"q", nil];

NSURL *targetedSearchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:queryString];
TWRequest *targetedRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:targetedSearchURL
                                                 parameters:parameters
                                              requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];


[targetedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
 {
    //Do something

 }];

}
```

Why does this leak? The call stack implicates the performRequestWithHandler, but the leak occurs regardless of what I do within the callback handler, even an empty implementation (as shown here) produces the leak. The leak occurs on the simulator and devices.

Comment: Are you referring to targetedRequest inside the block?

Comment: Nope, even an empty block produces the leak.

Comment: Is there any more information with regard to this issue? I have the exact same behaviour in a blank application that just makes a TWRequest

Comment: The issue has been reported and is awaiting resolution with Apple engineering. BugID #10929744. My application was approved despite the leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is the result of a memory leak in Apple's Twitter framework.